# AR SceneKit stock code (I have not added anything) throws a fatal error finding nil

Tags: swift, null, augmented-reality

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I am getting a fatal error running the stock code when creating an augmented reality app from SceneKit. I have not added any code at all but the line below is throwing a fatal error as nil is found.

```
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
```